# Remote client configuration

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

I'm looking for an approach: We have several applications that work with third-party applications. The settings of our applications have to be changed regularly (e.g. with every event, the third party tools require changed config items). The mentioned settings reside in the config-Files of our applications. Those applications are mostly operated in a LAN.

How can those changing (and required) settings be distributed in a elegant way so we change the settings once and the other applications pull those settings? Are there existing components in .net? How would you approach this problem? Maybe create a service and make all the applications act as config clients? Hope for some ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an updater for all distributed application (this will be one time update) and distribute one more time. That updater will read the updates from server and update the application config, and restart itself. You should have versions or date time stamp so that your updater will update only when there is change in your DB. BigL approach wont work if application is not online, but this will. You can skip the update if service is not available.

Comment: Ok thanks, but what do you mean by 'create an updater'? How would would you distribute? I'm not asking for code, but what mechanisms would be involved? I'm talking about 4 to 5 different applications which each require a certain subset of those settings.

Comment: Oh is see what you mean now if the service isn't online by my approach then the applications can't read the settings that's correct, so you would need a local copy in the app settings and if the applications starts and the service is available then you look for changes and change the config if needed.

Comment: Distributing database access to client is very un-secure, is not it? What if you change the DB password? @double, add the updater functionality to common assembly if you have. Else you create an assembly and call it from all the app(ps: all app need to be modified once)

Comment: Again I must ask, 'the updater functionality to common assembly if you have', what do you mean by that? Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to implement it from start or is there something existing which I haven't seen?

Comment: On all your application, do you have any common assembly? You can add your updater functionality to that assembly.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I was confused. Thank you, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question maybe you could try to store the settings in a central database and your applications would load the settings from there directly or through a service. I think i would choose a compact sql database.

And you need to store the settings in app.config too and if you start your app then look for the service and if available then update the settings in the local config if needed.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I had in mind as well. But I was wondering if there are any built-in mechanisms to do the distribution in .net...